# App goes to black screen and then restarts after Thread ends

Tags: java, android, runnable, android-download-manager, ui-thread

Alright, so I'm basically making a Native Android 'Update' Application (using Java). What the application does is download some files from the internet after a button is clicked.

The function downloadMaps() is executed when the 'Download' button is clicked:

```
    private void downloadMaps() {
    final DownloadManager downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://android.nsnav.com/update/maps.zip");
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

    request.setTitle("Maps");


    final long downloadId = downloadmanager.enqueue(request);
    final ProgressBar mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);


    mProgressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

    bUpdateMaps.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    prompt.setText("Downloading Maps Update");


    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        TextView percentage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.percentage);
        @Override
        public void run() {


            boolean downloading = true;

            while (downloading) {


                DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
                q.setFilterById(downloadId);

                Cursor cursor = downloadmanager.query(q);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int bytes_downloaded = cursor.getInt(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
                int bytes_total = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));

                if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                    downloading = false;
                    //registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
                }
                final int dl_progress = (int) ((bytes_downloaded * 100l) / bytes_total);


                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        mProgressBar.setProgress((int) dl_progress);
                        percentage.setText(Integer.toString(dl_progress) + "%");
                        //doTask();
                        if (dl_progress==100){
                            prompt.setText("Installing Maps Update");
                        }
                    }
                });
                cursor.close();
            }

        }
    }).start();



    registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(downloadmanager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));


}

BroadcastReceiver onComplete=new BroadcastReceiver() {

    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
        if (mapsZip){
            unzipFolderMaps();
            deleteMaps();
        }

        prompt.setText("Maps Download Completed!");
        bUpdateMaps.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
};
```

As you can see, I have also added a thread in the function which updates a Circular Progress Bar present in the layout of the application.

The thing is that when the Download is Complete, The App closes and then restarts again. And the code of the Broadcast Receiver at the end is not executed! How can I stop the app from crashing after the downloading is complete, and instead successfully make the code of the Broadcast Receiver be executed?

Comment: tell us the error or stacktrace

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher There is no error. The app runs just fine. I's just that it restarts by itself after the download is completed..

Comment: The whole basis of your question is that your app is **not** running just fine. You even say that it's crashing after the download is complete. So you should post the stacktrace from the crash.